# How to pass integer parameter in a SQL query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
        String id = Request.QueryString["id"];
        int no = Int32.Parse(id);
        string query = "select * from product_desc where d_id='"+no+"' ";
        SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
```

In this code, at the time of execution it gives an Error "Input string was not in a correct format".
How do I execute this query? Please give any suggestion or form link to solve this problem

Comment: Instead of using Query String use session it work fine

Answer (score 0):

Change code like below :

```
    string id = Request.QueryString["id"] != null ? Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() : "0" ;
    int no = Convert.ToInt32(id);
    string query = String.Format("select * from product_desc where d_id={0}",no);
    SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
```

Comment: Getting Same error Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: @SunilPatel Check in debugger, What is the value of Request.QueryString["id"]

Comment: The value of id is "1"

Comment: @Sunil Patel: Trim id and then conver to int.  int no = Convert.ToInt32(id.Trim());

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to do following thing.

```
 String id = Request.QueryString["id"];
 int no = Int32.Parse(id);
 string query = String.Format("select * from product_desc where d_id={0}",no);
 SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
```

I still have doubt that Request.QueryString["id"] does not return proper value at first place. Please confirm that so I can provide better improved answer.

Comment: if I'm passing String parameter in the place of no it return proper result but if I'm pass int parameter it gives an error-"Input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: Int32.Parse can throw that exception if id is not integer value otherwise it should work. Can you please update question with value and exactly which point you get error

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
{
    int no = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
    string query = String.Format("select * from product_desc where d_id={0}",no);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQL injection:**

SQL injection is a technique where malicious users can inject SQL commands into an SQL statement, via web page input.

Injected SQL commands can alter SQL statement and compromise the security of a web application.

So use `Parameters` to avoid SQl injection attack.

```
String id = Request.QueryString["id"];
int no = Int32.Parse(id.trim());
string query = "select * from product_desc where d_id=@d_id";
SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
Da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_id", no);
Da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Comment: @Sunil Patel: Trim id and then conver to int. int no = Convert.ToInt32(id.Trim());